# Sony VAIO laptop screen turns off after 3-4 hours

Tags: laptop, display, sony-vaio, overheating

I have a Sony VAIO laptop "VGN-FJ68GP". Every thing is working fine but after 3-4 hours only the screen turns off and the bottom part of the laptop gets too hot.

Why it is happening???

Comment: Normally when a laptop overheats completely, the whole laptop will shutdown to prevent any further damage, not just the screen. How old/new is the laptop? Have you tried dusting it off to see if maybe there are dust built-up in the fan?

Comment: @Darius Not the whole laptop shutdown when overheats, only the screen turns off

Comment: there should be some screen settings for power management provided by sony. did you check that? even though that won't go off while using the laptop that will go off if the laptop is not in use for a while

Comment: Sound like the screen is overheating?  Somewhere in the screen assembly, probably near the bottom, is the voltage generator for the cold-cathode tubes that light the screen.  Presumably the generator is overheating, due to a defect in it or in the tubes.  There's also the possibility that this unit has some tiny ventilation holes that have been blocked, or you have the unit backed up against something that prevents cooling.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Thanks, is there any other possibility for this screen issue????

Comment: If it truly is overheating, there's little possibility of it not being hardware-related -- I doubt, eg, that the software controls the oscillator frequency in the voltage generator.  But you should maybe check your judgement of whether it's overheating by comparing to other similar laptops that have been on several hours -- overheating in most circumstances would be almost unpleasant to touch.

Comment: It is added info to know if the light shuts off, or if the screen and light shuts off.  Did you do the flashlight trick to see if the picture exists?  Agrees with Daniel, check general air flow cooling, from what I have seen it doesnt take much dust to clog the airflow.